# Xcode commits don't upload to GitHub

Tags: xcode, github

After I cut Apple Watch app out of my Xcode project, I can't commit to GitHub..
I don't get any errors, just nothing shows up in GitHub.
I have checked, I am properly connected to the remote; other projects can upload to GH just fine?

Could this have anything to do with removing watch from project? (app builds fine).

Comment: are you using Xcode's integrated git client? and are you on a beta version of xcode

Comment: Using the integrated client yes.  No I'm on Xcode 8.3.3 :)

Comment: I have never had real good luck with the integrated client. It is supposed to improve with `Xcode9` but I use command line or `sourceTree`.  You could also try disconnecting from the remote all together then reconnecting. That may solve your issue.

Comment: I'll try these, thanks :)

Edit: Re-adding the remote worked! Thanks Daniel.